# How to sort the some co-ordinate in respect of x or y values of the co-ordinates?

Tags: sorting

Suppose, i have **10 points** with co-ordinates **(x,y)** .I have to sort those points in some manner (1) which **x** value is less than other it will be in earlier position than others (2) if **x** value of two points are the same then which **y** value is less than other will be in earlier position.So how can i sort these points?

Comment: Besides reading a C++ book, I would look at the compare-function you can pass to sort().

Comment: [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) has provied `operator<` just working as you expect, so it should be fine to just use it. What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda expression:

```
std::sort(pts.begin(), pts.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto & b) {
   return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
});
```

Not all compilers will accept `auto` as a lambda parameter type. So you may have to use the correct type name instead of `auto`.

If you are using a structure, a user defined less-than operator should help you:

```
struct Point 
{
    int x, y;
};

bool operator<(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{ 
    return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
}
```

To sort a `std::vector<Point>` according to your requirements, you just have to write

```
std::sort(pts.begin(), pts.end());
```

and it will use your user defined less-than operator.

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> points;

// populate

std::sort(points.begin(), points.end());
```

Comment: So `std::pair` is ordered from first to second?

Comment: @AndreasH. See [operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=(std::pair)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp), "Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically, that is, compares the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second elements."